# Can a general many-body Hamiltonian with quadratic and biquadratic terms be diagonalized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, fermions, eigenvalue, second-quantization

Can an arbitrary many-body hamiltonian in second quantization form with quadratic and biquadratic terms
$$H=\sum_{v_1,v_2} \alpha_{v_1 v_2}\ c_{v_1}^{\dagger}c_{v_2}+ \sum_{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4}\beta_{v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4}\ c_{v_1}^{\dagger}c_{v_2}^{\dagger}c_{v_3}c_{v_4}$$
be diagonalized into
$$H=\sum_{u} \epsilon_u c_{u}^{\dagger}c_{u}$$
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

---

I assume you talk about fermions (not that is matters much -- a similar argument would work for bosons).

Consider the 2-fermion Hamiltonian
$$
H=E_{00}+(E_{10}-E_{00})c_1^\dagger c_1 + 
(E_{01}-E_{00})c_2^\dagger c_2 + (E_{11}-E_{01}-E_{10}+E_{00}) c_1^\dagger c_1c_2^\dagger c_2\ .
$$
This Hamiltonian has eigenstates which are Fock states, with four independent eigenvalues $E_{00}$, $E_{01}$, $E_{10}$, $E_{11}$.

On the other hand, the most general Hamiltonian of two non-interacting fermions,
$$
H'=\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1 d_1^\dagger d_1 + \epsilon_2 d_2^\dagger d_2 \ ,
$$
has only *three* independent parameters, and thus only three independent eigenvalues. It therefore can by no means reproduce the energy spectrum of a general Hamiltonian $H$ above.

(If you want to see this concretely, choose e.g. $E_{00}=E_{01}=E_{10}=0$, $E_{11}=1$.)

Comment: Get it. Actually I was thinking about that with a fixed particle number N, the many-body Hamiltonian should be diagonalizable. Now I realize being diagonalizable with a fixed N doesn't mean being able to write H into quadratic terms. Because quadratic H cannot necessarily CONNECT N particle's energy spectrum with N+1 particle's energy spectrum.

Comment: You can do the same with 3 or more modes, where you project onto a fixed particle number: You will observe the same.  The point is that for free fermions, the n-fermion energies are always sums of n single-particle energies, which is a severe constraint.