# Approximating energy spectra of many-body Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, feynman-diagrams, approximations, many-body

This is related to the previous post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/449849/can-a-general-many-body-hamiltonian-with-quadratic-and-biquadratic-terms-be-diag). Although there is no way to diagonalize this Hamiltonian to obtain the exact eigenvalues, **is there a way to approximate the eigenvalues of such a Hamiltonian? (sources and a summary of the methods will be appreciated)** I know that approximation methods (like Feynman diagrams) exist for Green's functions, but I am not sure of one exists for many body energies.

Note: I thought about using perturbation theory from introductory Quantum Mechanics, but I wasn't sure if that would work because there are no perturbation parameters here.

Comment: You have essentially the most general Hamiltonian consists of 2-body and 4-body terms. I'm afraid there is no technique that will give you the energy spectra except numerical diagonalization, when the system consists of a small number of fermions.

Comment: Can the interactions be restricted to be local in some sense? On a 1D chain for example? if so, DMRG might be useful: https://tensornetwork.org/mps/algorithms/dmrg/

Comment: In the post you link, you can use perturbation theory to estimate the eigenvalues when $\beta$ is small relative to $\alpha$.